# Convert lxml object into string

Tags: python, lxml

I've just started using **lxml**, and I got this problem:

In the XML find I have an element with an attribute, for example:

```
<book category="COOKING">
```

I'm fine until the point I use:

```
for elt in doc.getiterator():

   ...

     a=elt.attrib
```

I get this object back: `{'category': 'COOKING'}`

How could I convert this into something usable, like a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `attrib` property is a dictionary (i.e. associative array). To get the `category` property value as a string you can write `elt.attrib['category']`